# preg_replace isn't working for some words/characters

Tags: php, regex, encoding

```
$str = 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\b)موسیٰ(?=\b)/u', 'Musa', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\b)سنا(?=\b)/u', 'suna', $str);
echo $str;
```

This fails to replace `موسیٰ`. It should give `کس نے Musa کے بارے میں suna ہے؟` but instead gives `کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں suna ہے؟`.

This is happening for all words that end with a `ٰ`, like `تعالیٰ` . It works for words where `ٰ` is in the middle of the word (no words begin with a `ٰ`). Does this mean that `\b` just doesn't work with `ٰ`? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that a word boundary matches in the following positions:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - *Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.*

The "offending" symbol is `U+0670` *`ARABIC LETTER SUPERSCRIPT ALEF`* belonging to *`\p{Mn}` (nonspacing mark Unicode category)*, and is thus a **non-word symbol**.  `\b` will match if it is preceded with a char belonging to `\w` (letter, digit, `_`).

Use unambiguous boundaries, only if the search phrase is not preceded/followed with word chars:

```
$str = 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\w)موسیٰ(?!\w)/u', 'Musa', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\w)سنا(?!\w)/u', 'suna', $str);
echo $str; // => کس نے Musa کے بارے میں suna ہے؟
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/wplWHc).

The `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind making sure there is no word char immediately before the subsequent consuming pattern, and `(?!\w)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure there is no word char immediately after the preceding consuming pattern.

Comment: A little explanation fix: *`\b` will match if it is preceded **or followed** with a char belonging to `\w`* (since there are two `\b`s in the pattern).

Comment: this question was the faint memory that had me wondering the impact of `u` on `\b`.

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not remember what PHP version `\b` started to be impacted by the `u` modifier. There were some earlier versions that did not work with it. I remember it from some SO post, not the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

<s>$str = 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟';
    $patterns=['/موسیٰ/u','/سنا/u'];
    $replacements=['Musa','suna'];
    echo preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$str);</s>

Perhaps we can spoof the word boundary by checking for space or start/end of line for the first pattern?

```
$str = 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟';
$patterns[]='/(?<= |^)موسیٰ(?= |$)/u';
$patterns[]='/\bسنا\b/u';
// or \s perhaps instead of blank space
$replacements=['Musa','suna'];
echo preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$str);
```

Output:

```
کس نے Musa کے بارے میں suna ہے؟
```

Comment: @Travis if my pattern fails when you use a different `$str`, please provide that case so I can test against it.  Otherwise, this simpler pattern seems right to me.

Comment: The \b is needed for words that are part of other words. `$str = 'he said hello';$patterns = ['/he/u'];$replacements = ['/Tom/u'];` in your example would give `Tom said Tomllo`.

Or just try `$str = 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنایا ہے؟';`. It won't work right.

Answer (score 0):

[Be careful that](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> `\b` and `\B`... are defined in terms of `\w` and `\W`.

`\w` matches word characters falling under ASCII table however while using `(*UCP)` option or `u` unicode modifier definition of `\w` changes to also include all other alphabets from other languages but not *combining marks*.

Saying that, `\b` never matches a position where a mark like `ٰ` sees a non-word character since the mark itself is considered a non-word character.

What you are trying to do is more like figuring out if there is any non-word character preceding or following word `موسیٰ` so asserting `\S` meta-character does the job:

```
(?<!\S)موسیٰ(?!\S)
```

Another way to accomplishing such a task would be [transliterating](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) whole input string using ICU library to remove all accents then trying to match word `موسی` which doesn't include the combining mark `ٰ`:

```
<?php

$strings = [
    'is' => 'کس نے موسیٰ کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟', // input string
    'wts' => 'موسیٰ' // word to search
];

array_walk($strings, function(&$value) {
    $value = transliterator_transliterate('[:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove;', $value);
});

// word boundaries now can be used
echo preg_replace('/\b' . $strings['wts'] . '\b/u', 'musa', $strings['is']);
```

Outputs:

```
کس نے musa کے بارے میں سنا ہے؟
```